# Many to Many Exclude on Multiple Objects

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer, related_name='deals')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...etc

class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    saved_deals = models.ManyToManyField(Deal, related_name='saved_by_customers', null=True, blank=True)
    dismissed_deals = models.ManyToManyField(Deal, related_name='dismissed_by_customers', null=True, blank=True)
```

What I want to do is retrieve deals for a customer, but I don't want to include deals that they have dismissed.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the many-to-many relationship and am having no luck figuring out how to do this query. I'm assuming I should use an exclude on Deal.objects() but all the examples I see for exclude are excluding one item, not what amounts to multiple items.

When I naively tried just:

deals = Deal.objects.exclude(customer.saved_deals).all()

I get the error: "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable"

If I say:

deals = Deal.objects.exclude(customer.saved_deals.all()).all()

I get "Too many values to unpack" (though I feel I should note there are only 5 deals and 2 customers in the database right now)

We (our client) presumes that he/she will have thousands of customers and tens of thousands of deals in the future, so I'd like to stay performance oriented as best I can. If this setup is incorrect, I'd love to know a better way.

Also, I am running django 1.5 as this is deployed on App Engine (using CloudSQL)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you use customer.saved_deals to get the list of deal ids to exclude (use values_list to quickly convert to a flat list).

This should save you excluding by a field in a joined table.

```
deals = Deals.exclude( id__in=customer.saved_deals.values_list('id', flat=True) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to change this:

```
deals = Deal.objects.exclude(customer.saved_deals).all()
```

To something like this:

```
deals = Deal.objects.exclude(customer__id__in=[1,2,etc..]).all()
```

Basically, `customer` is the `many-to-many` foreign key, so you can't use it directly with an `exclude`.

Answer (score 0):

Deals saved and deals dismissed are two fields describing almost same thing. There is also a risk too much columns may be used in database if these two field are allowed to store Null values. It's worth to consider remove dismissed_deals at all, and use saved_deal only with True or False statement.

Another thing to think about is move saved_deals out of CustomerProfile class to Deals class. Saved_deals are about Deals so it can prefer to live in Deals class.

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    saved = models.BooleandField()
    ...
```

A real deal would have been made by one customer / buyer rather then few. A real customer can have milions of deals, so relating deals to customer would be good way.

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    saved = models.BooleanField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerProfile)
    ....
```

*What I want to do is retrieve deals for a customer, but I don't want to include deals that they have dismissed.*

```
deals_for_customer = Deals.objects.all().filter(customer__name = "John")
```

There is double underscore between customer and name (customer__name), which let to filter model_name (customer is related to CustomerProfile which is model name) and name of field in that model (assuming CutomerProfile class has name attribute)

```
deals_saved = deals_for_customer.filter(saved = True)
```

That's it. I hope I could help. Let me know if not.